# Build type not found: android studio apk generation

Tags: android-studio, apk

[image: apk]

I can't choose the build type (release) when generating signed apk with android studio

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue.Problem was in loading native project to android studio.I opened the gradle file first then i was able to build my APK.